# В Чем может быть ошибка в коде?

Tags: python, python-3.x

***Код:***

```py
process_name = "..."
signatures = ""
mode = 1
v = "2.0.0 BETA"
scan_delay = 10

def crc(fileName):
    prev = 0
    for eachline in open(fileName, "rb"):
         prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)

import os,subprocess, zlib, time
sigs_path = "./sigs/" + process_name + "_sigs.txt"
sigs_local_path = "./sig.txt"

if mode:
   sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls' + process_name).decode("utf-8")
   f.write( sigs )
   f.close()

   print("Сигнатуры процесса" + process_name + "созданы!")

   f = open(sigs_local_path, 'w')
   f.write( sigs )
   f.close()

   while True:
       print("Сканирую игру ...")

       sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls ' + process_name).decode("utf-8")
       f = open(sigs_local_path, 'w')
       f.write( sigs )
       f.close()

       check = crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)

       if( check ):

           print( "Сигнатуры совпали, продалжаю..." )
           time.sleep(scan_delay);
           continue;
       else:
           print( "Сигнатуры НЕ СОВПАЛИ, закрываю игру!" )
           os.system('taskkill /IM "' + process_name + '" /F')
           break;

print("Античит FSK v "+v+" завершил свою работу.")
```

*stderr:*

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 19, in <module>
    f.write( sigs )
NameError: name 'write' is not defined
```

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, код. Кажется, я что-то такое на YouTube недавно видел у Хауди... :)

Comment: process_name = "..."
signatures = ""
mode = 1
v = "2.0.0 BETA"
scan_delay = 10
 
def crc(fileName):
    prev = 0
    for eachline in open(fileName, "rb"):
         prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
    return "%X"%(prev & 0xFFFFFFFF)
   
import os,subprocess, zlib, time
sigs_path = "./sigs/" + process_name + "_sigs.txt"
sigs_local_path = "./sig.txt"

Comment: https://pastebin.com/acnPNrRw кароче здесь код)

Comment: Да в вопросе напишите, а не в комментарии

Comment: Вы его редактировали вообще, это исходник?

Comment: Да я редактировал!

Comment: Нажмите на ссылку "править" под вопросом и добавьте к тексту вопроса полный текст ошибки и [mcve].

Comment: В 19 строке Вы обращаетесь к `f`, но до этого переменная нигде не объявлена.

Answer (score 1):

В 19 строке Вы обращаетесь к `f`, но до этого переменная нигде не объявлена.

Скорее всего, строки 19-21 лишние:

```py
...
if mode:
   sigs = subprocess.check_output('listdlls' + process_name).decode("utf-8")
   # f.write( sigs )  <----- Лишняя
   # f.close()        <----- Лишняя

   print("Сигнатуры процесса" + process_name + "созданы!")
...
```

Comment: Теперь у меня ошибка в
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 34, in <module>
    check = crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 9, in crc
    for eachline in open(fileName, "rb"):
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: './sigs/..._sigs.txt'

Comment: @oleggrief Конечно, ведь Вы не указали `process_name` в 1 строке (точнее он указан как "...").

Comment: я указал уже как бы)

Comment: я исправил ошибку просто создал sigs с game.exe_sigs.txt
а теперь мне пишет то что
eachLine не был указан до этого
Хотя как его туда указать не известно мне вообще Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 34, in <module>
    check = crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 10, in crc
    prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
NameError: name 'eachLine' is not defined

Comment: `/sigs/..._sigs.txt` - данный путь сформировался в строке 14 на основе `process_name`, следовательно он `...`

Comment: Говорю же поставил на game.exe на сапёра) теперь у меня ошибка другая Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 34, in <module>
    check = crc(sigs_path) == crc(sigs_local_path)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\AntiCheat.py", line 10, in crc
    prev = zlib.crc32(eachLine, prev)
NameError: name 'eachLine' is not defined

Comment: Простите, но, кажется, я больше не смогу Вам помочь. Нет никакого смысла оперировать техническими деталями, если Вы не знакомы с Python (или недостаточно хорошо знакомы).

Comment: Да я уже сделал у меня получилось исправить ошибки всего хорошего вам

Comment: Спасибо что помучались со мной)